# How did 'cordon bleu' come to be applied to cookery?

Tags: etymology

The ***cordon bleu*** -blue ribbon- was a ribbon worn by the Knights Grand Cross of the French Order of the Hoy Ghost, the highest order of chivalry under the Bourbon kings of France.

The OED entry on *cordon bleu* mingles examples of its use with the altogether ironic application of it, in Britain, to cookery.

Perhaps it was in the 19th century, when the British began to travel (especially after about 1850 by rail), that it became apparent that since British culinary tradition would never be able to hold a candle to the French, that Britain began to adopt a French vocabulary into its eating establishments.

Thus it was that as early as 1826 that we find a reference to the coveted blue ribbon to something as mere and ordinary as a cook.

> 1826   M. Kelly Reminisc. (ed. 2) II. 83   His chief French cook..was
>   a great artist, a real cordon bleu

Thackeray in 1849 writes:

> 1849   Thackeray Pendennis (1850) I. xxxv. 343   ‘How good this is!’
>   said Popjoy, good-naturedly. ‘You must have a cordon bleu in your
>   kitchen.’

By 1959 the *Good Food Guide* is awarding the chivalric ribbon to a British housewife:

> 1959   Good Food Guide 266   The wife's cooking is described by a
>   member as ‘Cordon Bleu’.

**Along the way, in the 19th century, something must have given impetus to this idea of good cooks (the first indication of the word *chef* in English is in 1845) being worthy of the blue ribbon of the highest chivalric order under the French kings. Does anyone know what it was, or anything of its history?**

Answer (score 6):

From its official website; [The name Cordon Bleu](http://www.lecordonbleu.com.au/about/en) ( the association with cookery was due to the feasts given to celebrate the high royal officials):

> - **has been used for the first time in relation to culinary excellence since the 16th century when King Henry III created one of the most important orders in France, “L’Ordre du Saint-Esprit.**” Symbolizing this order was the cross of the Holy Spirit which hung on a blue ribbon or un cordon bleu. **Due to the prestigious nature of this Order and the decadent feasts accompanying their ceremonies, the name Le Cordon Bleu became well recognized and celebrated.**
> - Le Cordon Bleu, as a culinary arts school, was founded in Paris in 1895 by the journalist and publisher of La Cuisinière Cordon Bleu magazine, Marthe Distel. On January 14th, 1896 the first cooking demonstration ever to be held on an electric stove was staged at Le Cordon Bleu in an effort to promote the magazine and launch the Paris cooking school. From this point on, the international reputation of Le Cordon Bleu spread rapidly. Great chefs came to the school to teach students further contributing to the world-renowned reputation of the school. As a result, students from a variety of countries were enrolling in classes as well as notable figures including Julia Child in 1950.

Comment: Excellent. Just what I was looking for.